# Odeint for solving 80 couple differential equations

Tags: python, ode, odeint

I am trying to solve a set of coupled ODE, basically rate equations, all of them are of the form dy/dt = f(y), using python's scipy's odeint library. I am shocked by the time it is taking to solve it. I have solved the same set of equations before in FORTRAN, where each time step took about 0.1 sec. Here, the same time-step is taking 30 minutes! I know python is slower than FORTRAN or C++ but this seems impossible.
What I have done:
I have defined a function which returns a list, where each element is the value of dy_i/dt. Then I call odeint over a run it over small-time interval. The code is like this, if that helps.

```
def matrix_reac(abundances, time):  
    matrix = []
    densityfactor = gas_density(time)/gas_density(time0)
    for ii in range(len(abundances)):
        mat1, mat2 = 0.0, 0.0
        for ik in range(len(reac_rate)):
            reaction_rate = reac_rate[ik]*(gas_temperature(time)/300)**reac_nu[ik]*np.exp(-reac_actT[ik]/gas_temperature(time))
            if (species_list[ii] == network['R1'][ik] or species_list[ii] == network['R2'][ik]):
                if ('M' in [network['R1'][ik],network['R2'][ik]] or 'XX' in [network['R1'][ik],network['R2'][ik]]):
                    mat1 = mat1 - densityfactor*reaction_rate*abundances[ii]
                else: 
                    mat1 = mat1 - densityfactor**2*reaction_rate*abundances[np.where(network['R1'][ik]==species_list)]*abundances[np.where(network['R2'][ik]==species_list)]    
                    
            if (species_list[ii] == network['R4'][ik] or species_list[ii] == network['R5'][ik]):    
                if ('M' in [network['R1'][ik],network['R2'][ik]] or 'XX' in [network['R1'][ik],network['R2'][ik]]): 
                    mat2 = mat2 + densityfactor*reaction_rate*abundances[np.where(network['R1'][ik]==species_list)]
                else:
                    mat2 = mat2 + densityfactor**2*reaction_rate*abundances[np.where(network['R1'][ik]==species_list)]*abundances[np.where(network['R2'][ik]==species_list)]       
        
#        print (species_list[ii],mat1,mat2)
        matrix.append((mat1+mat2)*sec_1day)
    return matrix  

tstep = np.linspace(t_days[0],t_days[0]+1,2)
sol22 = odeint(matrix_reac,species_abun,tstep, atol=1.0e-6, rtol=1.0e-6)
```

I tried using mxstep, and it considerably shortened the time, but apparently the results are wrong. That is because if I increase the mxstep the yield is increasing rapidly with it, so I cannot make it small.
Could someone suggest something. In principle, I have to run it for a long time range, so if 1 time-step takes 30 mins, it will just be unfeasible. In my mind it seems something I am not doing right, it cannot be this slow, and 80 coupled ODE is not an absurdly large set anyway.
Many thanks :)

Comment: Explicit loops are slow, you have 2 nested loops. Dictionary look-up is slow, you use that extensively. In general, python is good for prototyping. For production code use a compiled language. You might get some medium speed-up using JITcode, but that might not work well with the time-dependent external gas functions. // You could pre-compute `reaction_rate[ik]` so that that is not repeated for every run of the outer loop. Instead of collecting the contribution for each species from the network you could let the network distribute the contributions to the species.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will try to make some changes. However, if the loops are slowing it down, then the function itself would have taken long to compute, right? I can run the function with some value of (abundance, time) and it takes about 0.1 sec.  While just the odeint itself is taking infinite time. I have read posts from people solving 1000+ ODE in python, so I am still hopeful that this could be done. I suspect, the odeint solver is requiring too many time-steps internally to find a converged solution, and I am unable to optimize it.

Comment: That python loops are slow was one main point for introducing numpy. // You might want to experiment with the stepper methods and also compare to odeint. The results can be un-intuitive, sometimes Radau will be substantially faster than RK45, sometimes it is the other way. LSODA should be the same as odeint, emphasis on "should". The tolerances should be set to some sane values. One might think, for instance, that for plots a relative error level of 1e-2 is sufficient, but solve_ivp gets chaotic with this setting.

Comment: *You might get some medium speed-up using JITcode, but that might not work well with the time-dependent external gas functions.* – Two years ago, I implemented callbacks to Python functions for JiTCODE & Co, so this should be possible. Also, moving these kind of network look-ups out of the runtime to compile time is one of the main reasons JiTCODE exists, so it might very well be faster than Fortran. (Full disclaimer: I am the author of this module.)